# Alternatives for expanding monthly data to daily base level in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

There is an issue that I have recently solved, but would like to see if there is any better alternative.

Currently I have a redshift table which carries the monthly sales target for every products. The table looks like this

```
Start date     Product_id         Target
2018-08-01     100001             15000
2018-08-01     100002             12500
2018-08-01     100003             17500
2018-08-01     100004             16500
2018-08-01     100005             10000
2018-09-01     100001             15500
2018-09-01     100002             13500
2018-09-01     100003             18500
2018-09-01     100004             14500
2018-09-01     100005             14000
....           ...                ...
2018-12-31     100005             10000
```

And what I want to do is to replicate the table so as to change the granularity from monthly to daily and replicate the data every date i.e

```
    Start date     Product_id         Target
2018-08-01     100001             15000
2018-08-01     100002             12500
2018-08-01     100003             17500
2018-08-01     100004             16500
2018-08-01     100005             10000
2018-08-02     100001             15000
2018-08-02     100002             12500
2018-08-02     100003             17500
2018-08-02     100004             16500
2018-08-02     100005             10000
....           ...                ... 
2018-12-31     100005             20000
```

The currently solution is, I use left join with another table which contains the date value in day level like

```
    Date
  2018-08-01
  2018-08-02
  2018-08-03
  ....
  2018-12-31
```

And I do the left join in this way. I use the left join property to do the replication.

```
 SELECT 
   date_trunc('month', sales_tar.start_date), 
   dat.datevalue,
   sales_tar.product_id,
   sales_tar.target
 FROM 
   sales.sales_target sales_tar
 LEFT JOIN 
   datedata.caleanderdate dat ON sales_tar.start_date::date = 
   date_trunc('month', dat.datevalue)::date
 WHERE
   tar.start_date::date BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```

But I think that that there may be a more optimized method to solve the problem, that I may not aware of. 
Is there anyone which have a better solution, for replicating the data from monthly basis to day basis for whole year?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Your method is fine.

Comment: This is the best way for redshift. but you should also take a step back to consider why you need to replicate the table like this. Perhaps there is no need & you could just modify a join or something elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean up your query a bit by removing what seem like unnecessary type conversions:

```
SELECT st.start_date, cdd.datevalue,
       st.product_id, st.target
FROM sales.sales_target st LEFT JOIN 
     datedata.caleanderdate cd
     ON st.start_date = date_trunc('month', cd.datevalue)
WHERE st.start_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-12-31';
```

This assumes that the date values are already `date`s (which makes sense).

However, overall your approach makes a lot of sense.

You could tweak the calendar table so it had another column with the start of the month, say `yyyymm`.  Then you could phrase the query as:

```
SELECT st.start_date, cdd.datevalue,
       st.product_id, st.target
FROM sales.sales_target st LEFT JOIN 
     datedata.caleanderdate cd
     ON st.start_date = cd.yyyymm
WHERE st.start_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-12-31';
```

In some databases, that would be a performance boost.  I'm not sure if it would make much a difference in Redshift, though.